# 応答を破棄する方法について

Tags: python, flask

Flask / Python 初心者です。

不正アクセスの対策のためなのですが、
不正な URL が来たときに、応答を破棄させて、不正アクセス攻撃に対応したいです。
他のサイトを見ると、巨大な画像ファイルとしてバイナリを延々と送って、、などもあったのですが、サーバー負荷を掛けたくないため、またレスポンス400などを送ると次の攻撃を早くされてしまうため、何も返さずに要求を捨てたいのですが、Flask では対応方法があるのでしょうか?
Node.js では response.end 関連を実行しなければ対応できるのですが。。。

詳しい方、教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

通常の実践環境であれば、Flaskが処理をする前にnginxなどHTTPサーバがルートを処理するので、HTTPサーバの時点でマッチしないURLには応答しないようにすればいいのではないでしょうか。

参考ページ: [How can I tell nginx to silently ignore requests that dont match and let them time out instead of giving 404](http://goo.gl/EnWX46)

上のリンク先では、nginxでHTTPレスポンス444を返すという処理をわざと書く事で、実際には何も応答しないようにするテクニックが紹介されています。

Comment: さすが億単位の要求を処理するように設計された nginx ですね。444ステータスがほしいです。
Python では非同期処理で何かできないかと考えていましたが、Webサービス側でも何かできないか探すことにします。今はとりあえず process.sleep でタイムアウトさせています。

ご回答ありがとうございました。